# How to define custom type to prevent "is not assignable to type..." in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using the [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request/t) module and am running into a challenge in how I should define some options using typescript.

I have 2 headers that can be passed to the request:

```
interface GraphQLHeaders {
  'X-Api-Key'?: string
  'X-Account-Id'?: string
}
```

However if I do this TS throws errors:

```
 const headers: GraphQLHeaders = {}
 if(apiKey)
   headers['X-Api-Key'] = apiKey
 const client = new GraphQLClient(apiUrl, { headers })
```

The error is:

```
Type 'GraphQLHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers | string[][] | Record<string, string> | undefined'.
  Type 'GraphQLHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'GraphQLHeaders'
```

What is the proper way to do this? i.e. Restrict the headers to certain field but still be able to pass them?

Comment: Add to ```GraphQLHeaders``` index signature ```[key: string]: string```.

Comment: Won't that allow any headers?

Comment: You tell about some logical things. I tell you about missed type information to resolve the error. Is ```GraphQLHeaders``` your own defined type?

Comment: Yes. `GraphQLHeaders` is my own because I only want to allow 2 types of headers to be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a string index which says that no keys other than those specified are allowed

```
interface GraphQLHeaders {
  'X-Api-Key'?: string
  'X-Account-Id'?: string
}

type WithIndex<T> = T & {
    [key: string]: never;
}

const headers: WithIndex<GraphQLHeaders> = {}
```

When using this `WithIndex` utility type, you can still access any known properties and get their known value types.  You won't get a typescript error if you try to access invalid keys, but their values are always inferred to be `never`/`undefined`.

```
const key: string | undefined = headers['X-Api-Key'];
const bad: undefined = headers['something'];
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vwje2W)

Comment: How would you do that for a string? say if `headers` was an enum of values such as `'foo' | 'bar'` and I wanted to ensure my function only accepted `foo`?

Comment: Ahh - I was able to workaround this by defining a string enum type from an enum type